# Laravel Api , 2 Type of users , separate them or make one table

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, jwt

- I build Laravel Api  application
  i have 2 type of user on my application
- Doctor
- Patient

Each user type will have different user interface and access different types of data.

Their only similarity is they are using one web application
and the same **Authentication mechanism** 
i will use **JWT Auth**

-Is it better to put them all in one user table   or make two table for each type

Comment: It’s depend how you are managing different interface for two different users. You can add type enum field in users table to store users type. It’s simplest as well as easy to implement.

Comment: that's good , thank u

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware to seperate users with different roles